# How to filter column in excel containing multiple pieces of text

Tags: excel, search, filter, excel-formula, match

[image]I need to filter a column in excel for multiple words. Each cell contains a description (e.g. "Brand - Afternoon - Female - 25-34"; ""Brand - Afternoon - Male - 25-34"). I am looking to filter out the cells that contain specific words (i.e. "afternoon" or "morning" **&** "Female" or "male"). The words that I'm search for will be entered into a different cell (eg. H1, H7).

Using the following formula, i can get half of what i need : =FILTER(O2:O17,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(H1,O2:O17))), but that only filters for ONE of the values (i.e. "25-34")

The other issue that I'm having is that when searching for "male", anything labeled as "feMALE" will also show up. But i can't do an exact match, because the cells contain more than just one word ("Brand - Afternoon - Female - 25-34")

Thanks in advance. Below is an image of the excel column I'm trying to search/filter

[image]

Comment: Can you include some wanted results too with filter values? It's also best to include markdown sample data to copy paste to excel (easier).

Comment: Hi @JvdV, I've added an image to show you what I currently have. the drop down boxes result in output in the cells next to them (highlighted in blue). I want the filter to look in list to the right and then pull out and list any cells that contain the same words that are in blue. Again, the issue i see happening is that when the box says 'male', that it will find any that are actually 'female'

Comment: does this help? https://drive.google.com/file/d/15-yYghPxOThy5DDwgVHce5PAD9FNcxuH/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my take on your issue, using leading/trailing spaces to make for an exact result:

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=FILTER(E2:E17,(ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&C2&" ",E2:E17)))*(ISNUMBER(FIND(D2,E2:E17))))
```

And that boolean structure `(...)*(...)` is also how you could add the other criteria in there if need be.